# class="no-js" but javascript is working Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

when i visit any of my websites pages it says : class="no-js", but i do have javascript and it is working as wanted. Im using a plugin "Custom javascript" on wordpress, instead of using the hardcoded enqueue functions. But since it is working i dont understand what the problem is. But today another plugin im using stopped showing and gave me this error:
*noscript class="noscript-message" 
    Message: JavaScript is required for this content.*
So clearly something isnt right. Anyone have any idea as to why? below is my javascript code

```js
  jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
      img = new Image();
 div = document.getElementById('sidebar');
 img.onload = function() {
  div.parentNode.insertBefore(img, div.nextSibling).style.marginTop = "-115px";
 };
 img.src = '....../.png';
  x=document.getElementsByClassName("next page-numbers");
    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    x[i].innerText="Nästa →";
    }
    y=document.getElementsByClassName("prev page-numbers");
    for(var i = 0; i < y.length; i++){
    y[i].innerText="← Tillbaka";
    }

               jQuery( "li.current_page_item" ).each(function( index ) {
                  jQuery(this).parent('.sub-menu').slideToggle('fast');
                  jQuery(this).parent().parent('.sub-menu').slideToggle('fast');
     jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent('.sub-menu').slideToggle('fast');
                });

                jQuery( "li.current-menu-parent" ).each(function( index ) {
                  jQuery(this).parent('.sub-menu').slideToggle('fast');
                  jQuery(this).parent().parent('.sub-menu').slideToggle('fast');
                  jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent('.sub-menu').slideToggle('fast');
                });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever is adding `no-js` class to your body, is clearly not supposed to and that's what you need to look into.

The plugin that stopped working is probably checking if that class exists and, since it finds it, it just goes: *Sorry, mate, I require JavaScript to function properly*.

What you should do is pinpoint what is adding the `no-js` class to your body and why. That's the proper action. However, it might prove difficult and time consuming.

If you're after a quick and dirty solution, use this:

```
(function($){
  $(document).on('ready', function(){
    $('body').removeClass('no-js');
  })
})(jQuery)
```

It will remove `no-js` class from your `<body>` element as soon as DOM is built, using `jQuery` (already present in WordPress), which is `JavaScript`. If the script runs, `js` is functional, so the class should not be present on `<body>`, right? I'm running the script on `document.ready` because most scripts in WordPress are bound to `window.load`, which runs after `document.ready`, so chances are this script will run before your plugin's.

---

There is a chance that your plugin is checking whether or not `no-js` is present on `<body>` in `php`, before the page is actually built and `javascript` run on it. If you want to remove the class at that level, you should add this to your theme's `functions.php`:

```php
add_filter( 'body_class', 'remove_nojs_from_body', 10, 1 );
function remove_nojs_from_body( $classes ) {
  if (in_array('no-js', $classes)) {
      unset( $classes[array_search('no-js', $classes)] );
  }
  return $classes;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and i went into it and checked. Because noone likes quick fixes, it just has to work properly. So i checked into:
<?php
if (!is_admin()) add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'woothemes_add_javascript' );
if (!function_exists('woothemes_add_javascript')) {
 function woothemes_add_javascript( ) {
  
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );    
  wp_enqueue_script( 'thickbox' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'superfish', 

And i found that my "sidebar-init.php" ive been working on interfered and broke something. So i redesigned some code and i got it working properly now. Thank you